# Split dataframe into list and remove the index

Tags: r

I want to split a dataframe into list based on an index, but in the list, I don't want to include the index.

For example I want to split the dataframe in the mtcars data based on mpg.

```
data(mtcars)
lst <- split(mtcars, mtcars$mpg)
```

The `lst` still has mpg in each element. I hope not to include mpg. Is there any easy way to accomplish this? Thanks.

Comment: `unname(split(mtcars, mtcars$mpg))`

Comment: `lst <- split(mtcars, mtcars$mpg); lst <- lapply(lst, function(x) x[, -1])` works too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `group_split` from `dplyr` which has the `keep` parameter that takes a boolean to either keep the column or not

```
library(dplyr)
mtcars %>% 
    group_split(mpg, keep = FALSE)
```

---

With `base R`, the column can be removed with `setdiff`

```
split(mtcars[setdiff(names(mtcars), "mpg")], mtcars$mpg)
```

Comment: If I run this code: car <- unname(split(mtcars, mtcars$mpg, drop = TRUE))
car[[1]] still has mpg as a column.

Comment: @Roger Sorry I thought you want to remove the names.  Updated the post

Answer (score 2):

This is a decent use case for the oft-forgotten `plyr` package. I just used the top three rows of `mtcars` for illustration purposes:

```r
library(plyr)
dlply(head(mtcars,3), "mpg", function(x) x[, -1])
#> $`21`
#>   cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
#> 1   6  160 110  3.9 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
#> 2   6  160 110  3.9 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
#> 
#> $`22.8`
#>   cyl disp hp drat   wt  qsec vs am gear carb
#> 1   4  108 93 3.85 2.32 18.61  1  1    4    1
#> 
#> attr(,"split_type")
#> [1] "data.frame"
#> attr(,"split_labels")
#>    mpg
#> 1 21.0
#> 2 22.8
```

<sup>Created on 2019-04-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>